# How to test for if browser supports clipboardData

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to test (on page load) if the browser has a `clipboardData` property on a paste event? (Currently only Chrome has it.)

I tried to `.trigger()` the paste event with jQuery, but it doesn't work. (No `.originalEvent` property on a `.trigger()`'ed event)

I want to test for this on page load and prior to the user's paste.

Comment: try-catch for reference-errors?

Comment: @WaleedKhan try-catch is the way to go, but I want to test for it prior to the user's paste. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it is a window property

```
if (window.clipboardData) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or if it is attached to the event

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        // do event stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: clipboardData is a property of the `paste` event

Comment: ...and the `copy` event. So?

Comment: (it's not a property of window). Also I want to test before the user pastes.

Comment: In Chrome 24 on Linux Mint I'm getting undefined for both, actually, on both `copy` and `paste`.

Comment: Works for me on latest Chromium on Linux Mint and Chrome 24 on LM

Comment: Do you mean if(window.ClipboardEvent)? Because window.clipboardData returns undefined in Chrome.